# What does model name means for MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro

From my local Apple reseller I get a model name of MacBook Pro I'm interested in.

MacBook Pro **MR942**

But US apple.com site doesn't have this model for MacBook Pro of the same configuration.

What does it mean? Fake MacBook?

How to read that model name?

Does Apple have some search engine (some special page or application) where I can type MacBook's model name and get full info about the device?

One:
[image: Example one]

Two:
[image: Example two]

Three:
[image: Example three]

Comment: That's probably specific to your local Apple Reseller; it not an Apple PN#.  Without context, it would be impossible to tell.

Comment: @Allan, what context do you mean?

Comment: *Where* did you get that PN# from?

Comment: Google gets a quarter million hits for "MacBook Pro MR942"

Comment: @Tetsujin, Exactly. And what does it mean? Google has indeed, but Apple keep silence.

Comment: @Allan, I've added three screenshots as an example.

Comment: From the answers below, MR942 is a *partial* order number.  It's not Apple's responsibility to ensure people use PN#s correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **MR942** designator is most likely a partial **Apple Manufacture Part Number**, e.g.: **MR942LL/A**

From **[CDW](https://www.cdw.com/product/Apple-MacBook-Pro-with-Touch-Bar-15.4in-Core-i7-16-GB-RAM-512-GB-SSD/5179761?cm_cat=google&cm_ite=5179761&cm_pla=NA-NA-Apple_NM&cm_ven=acquirgy&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMI6syhmNHC3gIVDJ6fCh29fAfZEAAYASAAEgJE7fD_BwE:G:s&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6syhmNHC3gIVDJ6fCh29fAfZEAAYASAAEgJE7fD_BwE&s_kwcid=AL!4223!3!76209055579!p!!g!!mr942ll%2Fa&s_kwcid=AL!4223!3!76209055579!p!!g!!mr942ll/a)**, an **Apple Authorized Reseller**, in the image below see the yellow highlighted section.

[image: CDW]

---

According to **[Mactracker](http://mactracker.ca)**, a **MacBook Pro** with **MR942** which they call it an **Order Number**, and which by the way is an incomplete **Order Number**, e.g. **MR942LL/A**, is a **MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) 2.6 GHz Space Gray**, as shown in the yellow highlighted section of the image below.

**Mactracker** is probably mistakenly calling an **Apple Manufacture Part Number** an **Order Number**.

[image: Mactracker]

---

Looking on the box my **MacBook Pro** came in, this convention corresponds to what's labeled as "**(1P) Part No.**", albeit a different sequence nonetheless, it matches the pattern of **?????LL/A** and as such **MR942** is in all likelihood a partial **Apple Manufacture Part Number**.

Answer (score 1):

Part numbers for MacBooks (and Apple products in general) [take a number of forms:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201300)

- MacBook Early 2016
- Macbook Pro 11,4
- MJLQ2xx/A

By common convention the first one is how they are often referred to online. The second one is, for all intents and purposes, the *version* of the Mac. In the above example that would be the eleventh major version of MacBook Pro and the fourth minor revision of that particular model. The last one is the Apple Part number.

Note that these are for desktop/laptop Macs. iPhones and iPads are a bit different.

Your part number does not confirm to any of these conventions so it is likely something used locally. Possibly the in-store SKU (or stock/part number) which has no relevance outside the specific store or chain of stores.

If you need to reference a particular model of Mac you will need one of those designations. If you re-visit the store and are allowed to handle the Mac you want, go to the Apple Menu and select the first item in that menu: "About This Mac" you will get something like this

[image: About This Mac (MacBook Air)]

Note that the model designation is just below the information about the Operating System and describes this Mac as  a MacBook Air (Early 2014).

Once you have that information you can then go to other stores to compare or online to look up specs and prices.